# How to Combine Two CSS Animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to replicate the menu design used by:

https://www.pandaexpress.com/menu/appetizers

I think I am at the point where I need to use javascript/jquery, but I'm very new and unsure of my next step.  When the user hovers over an image the image seems to slide into focus and display information below.  I have tried to isolate this into separate actions, modeled by the following jfiddles:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lrqu8L0q/3/ (enlarges and focuses image on hover)
https://jsfiddle.net/4ud7wnop/1/ (slides down to reveal text on hover)

I tried combining them but when I add the

```
<p>This text is displayed on a downward slide after hover</p>
```

to the first jfiddle the paragraph isn't hidden.

Now I'm having trouble trying to think of a way to combine the both. I think I need to use javascript/jquery to create a function that applies the slide down to reveal text after the image enlarge has been completed.  I'm very new to web design as a whole and am especially shaky with javascript and jquery.

I was wondering if I could write a function that checks if the image has expanded on enlarge yet, and after it's reached a desired height/width run the text slide function.  Really not sure how to do this.. could someone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Use a `@keyframes` animation.  If you want more information about `@keyframes` animations, I will post an answer to explain it.

Comment: @NathanielSantley Let me do some reading and then I'll let you know!

Comment: Ok, I'll wait for your response.

Comment: I could use an explanation @NathanielSantley  I get the general idea but I'm not sure how I could use this idea to blend the two jfiddles

Comment: One sec.  Do you want to blend the two jfiddles from seperate files or do you want to blend the animations on the same page?

Comment: I want both animations to occur either simultaneously or one after the other

Answer (score 2):

I merged them together here: https://jsfiddle.net/danbovey/53ya31gm/

The main problem was, you need the image to be larger to cover over any detail text you may have.

I have commented on most changes I added in the fiddle. But here's the key parts:

I renamed the `bg` element to `tile`, it seemed more appropriate. Instead of working with `height` for the `.slide-down` class, I created a transform on the details div when the tile is hovered.

```
.tile:hover .details {
    transform: translateY(150%);
}
```

You can learn about CSS transforms here: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transforms/

The percentage of the transform can be calculated as the height of img / height of details - `300px / 200px = 150%`

To create the growing effect, a pseudo `:before` element adds a white area the same size of the image before the tile, and when hovered, grows to 25px around each edge. And an identical element is added to the details div.

```
.tile:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  content: '';
}

.tile:hover:before {
  top: -25px;
  left: -25px;
  width: calc(100% + 50px);
  height: calc(100% + 50px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want here?
https://jsfiddle.net/Lrqu8L0q/9/

```css
.thumbnail{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display:block;
  z-index:999;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.bg:hover {
    transform: scale(1.25)
}
.bg{
  width: 150px;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: teal;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.slide-down {
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
  transition: height 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: teal;
}
.bg:hover .slide-down {
  height: 140px;
}
.container{
  position: relative;
  left: 150px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg">
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/70497/pexels-photo-70497.jpeg" class="thumbnail"/>
    <div class="slide-down">
      <h2>Title</h2> 
      <p>This text is displayed after a downward slide on hover</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically what you need to do is put both your requirement into 1 combined object (in this I mean put both the Image & Text inside 1 container) like in the above example

```
<div class="bg">
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/70497/pexels-photo-70497.jpeg" class="thumbnail"/>
    <div class="slide-down">
        <h2>Title</h2> 
        <p>This text is displayed after a downward slide on hover</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Both of them are put inside 1 container with class `.bg`, then what you want is to `hover` the **container** (not the thumbnail or description itself) and trigger both the `scaling` & `slide-down` the menu detail, you can do this by adding the `CSS`

```
.bg:hover { ... }
```

For the `scaling`, you need to put it together with the `container` so all the elements inside will be scaled to, then for the description inside it, you need to use

```
.bg:hover slide-down { ... }
```

This is where you set the animation that will expand the description of the menu (for explanation, this `CSS` will trigger on `.bg` hover, and applied to the element `.slide-down` inside of it)

Comment: Good thing I didn't try to tackle this with JavaScript!!